# Zendesk Apps: How to create Event listeners after app was initialised?

Tags: javascript, events, frameworks, zendesk

I'm currently working on an app which has `brand_field_id` as one of it's parameters. It will hold the Custom Ticket Field ID for "Brand". The thing is: it **is not** required as the user might want or not to use the functionality it provides. Expected behaviour:

- If this field is filled with an ID, an event listener for it's `.change` will be added on the custom field (and stuff will get done);
- If it is left blank, nothing should happen. It means user opted to not use it.

Zendesk already provides the perfect listener for [Custom Ticket Field change event](https://developer.zendesk.com/apps/docs/agent/events#custom-ticket-field-change-event), which works like this (dynamically using `brand_field_id`):

```
events: {
  "ticket.custom_field_ticket.custom_field_{{brand_field_id}}.changed": "myCustomFieldChangedFunction"
}
```

... aaand it would be really awesome if **the app didn't crash when `brand_field_id` is empty**.

Since I don't want the app crashing if `brand_field_id` is left blank, I figured to validate it before adding the event listener, but didn't manage to get it done. I've tried a few variations of the following code within `app.created` event, but all unsuccessful.

```
if(!_.isEmpty(this.setting('brand_field_id'))){
  console.log('Brand change event added');
  this.events['ticket.custom_field_ticket.custom_field_{{brand_field_id}}.changed'] = 'brandChangedHandler';
}
```

`console.log` gets fired, so the validation is ok. Unfortunately the event never fires for the custom field.

So **my question is**: how can I add an event listener *on the go*? Or is there another way to achieve what I need?

---

I've even [posted about this in Zendesk's community](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/communities/public/posts/203460486-Is-there-a-way-to-register-interest-in-custom-field-changes-dynamically?page=1#community_comment_206441887) on a similar thread but no answers so far. The *workaround* I've found there actually *works*, but I'm not very fond of it:

```
events: {
  // [...]
  '*.changed': 'anyFieldChangedHandler'
},
// [...]
anyFieldChangedHandler: function(e){
  // If the changed field was {brand_field_id}
  if(!_.isEmpty(this.setting('brand_field_id')) && e.propertyName === 'ticket.custom_field_'+ this.setting('brand_field_id')){
    this.brandChangedHandler(e);
  }
},
```

It's much too broad and will fire whenever **any** field is changed on the ticket. I would like to find a better, cleaner and more elegant solution.

Comment: Hi Michael, could you simply bind a new event listener with jQuery like the following - `this.$(‘.some-element-in-app’).on(‘click’, function() { /* do some thing. */  })`, replacing the element with the element you need?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat as I am aware of how difficult it is to find answers related to the Zendesk Apps framework.

I would do something like this

```
events: {
  "ticket.custom_field_ticket.custom_field_{{brand_field_id}}.changed":"itChanged"
},
itChanged: function(){
      if(ticket.custom_field_ticket.custom_field_{{brand_field_id}} !== null && ticket.custom_field_ticket.custom_field_{{brand_field_id}} !== undefined){
          //Your custom field exists and has a value. Do something with it.
      }
      else{
          //Your custom field does not exist and/or does not have a value. do nothing
      }
}
```

Would something like this work for your app? I'm not sure if this would have the same functionality as `!_.isEmpty()` but you might give it a try. I use this a lot in my app sometimes just as a safe guard incase my app loads faster than the actual ticket, which causes some values to be "undefined" at the time the app loads.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply, indeed it's hard to find what you need sometimes. Anyways, I see two problems about your code: 1) To register `"ticket.custom_field_ticket.custom_field_{{brand_field_id}}.changed"` as an event is a part of the problem in my question: it throws a JS error: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {{brand_field_id}}.changed`. 2) In the 'itChanged` function, `ticket.custom_field_ticket.custom_field_{{brand_field_id}}` does not evaluate and is not even valid JS syntax. The expression evaluates as an event listener because de framework parse the string.

Comment: About the problem 1) above, I mean it throws the error if the field is left blank (no value at all).